# Where should I place braces?

Tags: java, layout, curly-braces

I was wondering if I should place my braces like this

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){

}
```

or should I place them like this?

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{

}
```

witch one is "better" or more common ?

Comment: First one is *common*. Please stop posting this kind of questions.

Comment: This is entirely a matter of personal preference (although I too prefer the first one) either way this sort of question isnt with SO's scope

Comment: Follow http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html  like most people do. That'll match your first for loop.

Comment: First one is default by many IDEs (Eclipse, NetBeans), so you will probably see it more often. I started with second version (after learning a little bit of PASCAL :D) but moved to first one. Anyway it is your choice and wont affect created application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is *subjective* issue, not *objective*, and therefore not a suitable question for Stack Overflow.

**Pro tip**: If you're working on a team, your team should have agreed on a style that will be consistently used through all source files. Adhere to it. Don't be the guy that opens other people's files, changes the format to your preference, and then commits back to the repository. Dick move there, and grounds for firing IMO.

**Advanced pro tip**: Spend your time worrying about things that actually *matter*. An unbelievable amount of blood has been spilled in the programming community arguing over garbage like this.

**Super-advanced pro tip**: The [one true brace style](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style#Variant%3a_1TBS), and the *right* way to place braces, is on the same line as in your first example. This is also the guideline recommended by the [Java code conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconvtoc-136057.html).

Answer (score 0):

The former the preferred syntax from Oracle's Java Code Conventions:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconvtoc-136057.html

Specifically:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-142311.html#454

And thus is relatively common.  In general: pick a coding convention (as a team, if it's a team) and stick to it.   What is now Oracle's conventions were basically the original, for Java, and thus fairly commonly adopted, at least as a starting point - but you're free to whatever you prefer (as a team / company / etc.).

Comment: Ken Thompson and Dennis Ritche (RIP) came first, and Oracle was really Sun when those guidelines were originally published.

Comment: Yeah, but its funny how most of C# programmers put braces like he wrote in second case.

Comment: @brano88 When I was developing in C#, I only did it like that because my IDE (MSVS 2010) would automagically change it to that format as I type :P

Comment: @Magtheridon96: You can change it to your preference.